# Calling multiple command-line commands from vbscript / wscript in a single shell instance

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript, cmd, wsh

I'm trying to improve the performance of my vb script. I need vbs to programmatically transform and import xml files into an MS Access database, and that works fast. After I run an xsl transform on a directory full of xml files (2000), I run the import into Access. This takes about a second.

I'd like to add a Python (script or executable) step just before the import to do some processing of the XML. This works fine on stand-alone XML files.

My question is how to run the Python code on multiple files without the process of opening and closing the command window taking up so much time. Running the following example code looks ok, but takes about 30 seconds for 400 times. Is there a way to run the Python sequentially in one command-line instance? I don't want to concatenate 2000+ calls. Can I do it in one window?

```
'usage: wscript multi-dir.vbs c:\my\xml\xml

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.GetFolder(WScript.arguments.item(0))
Set fc = f.Files
Dim filecount
filecount = 0
filecount = CInt(filecount)

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\my\xml"

'Maybe call the oShell.run command here?

For Each f1 In fc
    'Load an xml file, transform it, save it
    'xml.load f1.Path
    'xmlTransformedResult = xml.transformNode(xsl)

    'and each command to run here?   <--------- ?????
    'the type command is just an example command here, it would be the python call.
    oShell.Run "%comspec% /k type TransformOutput.xml", 0, False

    'Now do the Access Import here
    'objAccess.ImportXML xmlTransformOutputFile, 2
    filecount = filecount + 1
Next

WScript.Echo "Processed " & filecount & " files."
```

Comment: why can't you do everything in python?

Comment: Drop the `%comspec%` and run `python.exe` directly. You need to do that anyway unless you want to modify the Python script to loop over the files itself. With that said: why can't you simply process the XML files in VBScript?

Comment: Someone else is using Python and its libraries to analyze the text in the xml and add a new field. VBScript works great for the Access XML Import, so I need to use both. The Python code takes a single file in as input and returns a modified xml file as output. I'm looking for how not to generate all the cmd processes and keep it running inside one.